# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest') angular + ipfs build on https

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ipfs

Hello I have issue: App works perfectly on local environment. After making prod or dev build I got error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest')
```

and it comes from venedor:

```
sha512: function () {
    var _ref = _asyncToGenerator(function* (message) {
      if (crypto.web) {
        const buffer = yield crypto.web.subtle.digest('SHA-512', message.buffer);
```

Please for hints, I have lack of ideas.

PS. I am using https certificate but it is not finished yet, waiting for response from cert provider.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone getting undefined digest. Like I said I was meanwhile SSL cert installation in hosting. You have to have content over HTTPS origin like docs said.